# DataGridView: custom cells destroyed when inserting/deleting/sorting rows

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a grid where I need to use different cell types in the same column, based on the value of a field in the row.

This is a simplified version of the code I use to obtain these custom cells:

```
/* ... */

myGrid.DataSource = bs;

bs.DataSource = myDataSource;
bs.ResetBindings(true);

const int customCol = 5;

var rowsCount = bs.Count();

for (int r = 0; r < rowsCount; r++)
{
    MyType row = (MyType)bs[r];
    if (row.SomeVal == true)
    {
        var cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
        cell.DataSource = MyList;
        cell.ValueMember = "ID";
        cell.DisplayMember = "Desc";
        myGrid(customCol, r) = cell;
    }
}
```

In this example myGrid is bound to a BindingSource, and has a column (column index = 5) that is a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, so its cells are of type `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`, but for some specific rows I want cells to be of type `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`.

With this code the grid is correctly rendered, but as soon as I add or delete a row, or sort the grid, all my custom cells are reverted to standard ones.

I think that rather than alter cells after they are created, I should somehow intercept creation routine and alter their type as soon as they are created.

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to do this, as I can't find something like a "BeforeCellCreation" event.

Comment: I guess you should not change the cell type at run-time. You can define the cell as a combo in design-time then use it as such either you have 1 item or more.

Comment: Column 5 in the “GRID” may well be a `TextBoxColumn`, HOWEVER, what is the type of the column in the underlying data source (BindingSource) which column 5 is bound to? When you add the `ComboBoxCell` to the grid this goes off without a hitch, however, as soon as you “select” an item from the combo box and try to leave the cell… you will get the grids `DataError` because the underlying data sources cell is NOT a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`. Can you elaborate as to what you are trying to do in a general sense?